# Why does a Typescript type conditional on `T extends undefined`, with T instantiated with `boolean`, resolve T to `never`?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

The following code is trying to define the type of a function that's called with no arguments when its generic argument is `undefined`, but with 1 argument for any other argument type. (There may well be better ways to accomplish this, which I'd love to see links to in the comments, but the question is about why Typescript works differently than I expected.)

When `T extends undefined` is false, `T` appears to turns into `never` in the else branch, but only inside a function parameter list...

```
type OptionalArgBroken<Arg> = Arg extends undefined ?
  () => void :
  (arg: Arg) => void;

const suppressArgBroken:OptionalArgBroken<undefined> = function() { };
suppressArgBroken(); // Fine

const haveArgBroken:OptionalArgBroken<boolean> = function(b:boolean) { };
haveArgBroken(true); // Type error
```

As you can see on the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwIICcDmAQjkgNYQoA8ueAfFALxTVQQAew5AJgM5QCuKThABmCFBE5QA-AFgAUFCgAKAJQM6ANyQJJALnmKlafLqb419Tds4BuefIDGqbsCjc+YMDgjdu1IqTkunCIqJj+xGSUAkKi4px0jMICDqEoqlAA3lAAvnZy7p7evhGB6Sr5js6uABZoGhClUcHwyOjY+AFRFABGSEgYEGgoiVDJKKltSj26fQNDKGrZefJ1DU3kSsA4fBAVUAD0B1AAKuDQEDjEOKbUfAC25K5IwlCgkFAA5Nu7n1AIvBQSFcaF8CDw6B6gzeSCgYGMaEeHBwUBeb3OX3EDRwnwAdEoAEwAZgALABWFT2OTyI5QABiCFY-xQ3DACG8kh6ICgNWAwDA3F0RzwCGANT4PVxTnuB3uCAcxG4L2ABzOkAAygqEPADgD3D4DkSAIwAdjJRv0cne0BCbXC+AA6kgcCRuFR8KMANrUAC6LHYXF4npiIjEEj9sgUygsVh0UEthmMeFu5nUUC0OkqcicLNchS8Pj8judrpaaXteCdLrdIbiElG40mqAyy3y+eKRcrJe4qizOZcPPqjWL1bLdo6XervX6g2GDZSaWmsxnCyWuXya2Hk9dWx2eyzNOOJxqAP+gOBbxq0G4iOgXiQUIg9ygoJ5fIFQoOIrFEqlSBlcoKkgSrCCqaoQJqODaiqeq7NwhqmualrWlAACyaBkNw6rkNwEAnAw-CCKG8T+hwgi8LWYaSFIXwgD4fymJ8QKfFUuZoRhPjYSyEC6OhmFcbh+GMJ8dHcJ8WYoQAogG5EAKpEXWnAUCcoz4WwZE8IRsRUdItH0fGmJICx1LZtU7H8TheH9AZ0kadw8nafEFCUfEowifR+T9q4fGcZZx7eNApi2YGDnERI07zHOBFMUZNhAA), the last line above gives the type error

> Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)

After reading https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751, I tried wrapping `Arg` and `undefined` in `[]`s, and that appears to have fixed the problem:

```
type OptionalArgWorks<Arg> = [Arg] extends [undefined] ?
  () => void :
  (arg: Arg) => void;

const suppressArgWorks:OptionalArgWorks<undefined> = function() { };
suppressArgWorks(); // Fine

const haveArgWorks:OptionalArgWorks<boolean> = function(b:boolean) { };
haveArgWorks(true); // Fine
```

Even though that fix worked, this is not the same problem:

```
type MakesSenseT = undefined extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'
const MakesSense:MakesSenseT = 'yes';

type ExtendsUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'

const MakesSenseToo : ExtendsUndefined<undefined> = 'yes';
const MakesSenseThree : ExtendsUndefined<boolean> = 'no';
```

**Why did my original code not work?**

[Typescript Playground Link for the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwIICcDmAQjkgNYQoA8ueAfFALxTVQQAew5AJgM5QCuKThABmCFBE5QA-AFgAUFCgAKAJQM6ANyQJJALnmKlafLqb419Tds4BuefIDGqbsCjc+YMDgjdu1IqTkunCIqJj+xGSUAkKi4px0jMICDqEoqlAA3lAAvnZy7p7evhGB6Sr5js6uABZoGhClUcHwyOjY+AFRFABGSEgYEGgoiVDJKKltSj26fQNDKGrZefJ1DU3kSsA4fBAVUAD0B1AAKuDQEDjEOKbUfAC25K5IwlCgkFAA5Nu7n1AIvBQSFcaF8CDw6B6gzeSCgYGMaEeHBwUBeb3OX3EDRwnwAdEoAEwAZgALABWFT2OTyI5QABiCFY-xQ3DACG8kh6ICgNWAwDA3F0RzwCGANT4PVxTnuB3uCAcxG4L2ABzOkAAygqEPADgD3D4DkSAIwAdjJRv0cne0BCbXC+AA6kgcCRuFR8KMANrUAC6LHYXF4npiIjEEj9sgUygsVh0UEthmMeFu5nUUC0OkqcicLNchS8Pj8judrpaaXteCdLrdIbiElG40mqAyy3y+eKRcrJe4qizOZcPPqjWL1bLdo6XervX6g2GDZSaWmsxnCyWuXya2Hk9dWx2eyzNOOJxqAP+gOBbxq0G4iOgXiQUIg9ygoJ5fIFQoOIrFEqlSBlcoKkgSrCCqaoQJqODaiqeq7NwhqmualrWlAACyaBkNw6rkNwEAnAw-CCKG8T+hwgi8LWYaSFIXwgD4fymJ8QKfFUuZoRhPjYSyEC6OhmFcbh+GMJ8dHcJ8WYoQAogG5EAKpEXWnAUCcoz4WwZE8IRsRUdItH0fGmJICx1LZtU7H8TheH9AZ0kadw8nafEFCUfEowifR+T9q4fGcZZx7eNApi2YGDnERI07zHOBFMUZNhAA)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As written,

```
type OptionalArgBroken<Arg> = Arg extends undefined ?
    () => void :
    (arg: Arg) => void;
```

is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because the type being checked, `Arg`, is a naked generic type parameter.

"Distributive" means that if the `Arg` passed in is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then the type will be evaluated for each member of the union separately and then united back together (so the operation is *distributed* across the union).  In other words, `OptionalArgBroken<A | B | C>` will be the same as `OptionalArgBroken<A> | OptionalArgBroken<B> | OptionalArgBroken<C>`.

This is likely not your intent, as evidenced by the fact that you are happy with the results when you wrap your check in `[]` (which makes the checked type no longer "naked" by "clothing" it).

---

Furthermore, the TypeScript compiler treats the `boolean` type as a shorthand for the union of `true` and `false`, the so-called [boolean literal types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/more-literal-types-in-typescript#boolean-literal-types):

```
type Bool = true | false;
// type Bool = boolean
```

If you hover over `Bool` in your IDE with IntelliSense, you will see that `Bool` above is displayed as `boolean`.

This might be surprising if you think of `boolean` as a single type and not a union of two other types.  And one place this shows up is when you pass `boolean` to a distributive conditional type: `OptionalArgBroken<boolean>` is `OptionalArgBroken<true | false>` which is `OptionalArgBroken<true> | OptionalArgBroken<false>` which is

```
type OABBool = OptionalArgBroken<boolean>;
// type OABBool = ((arg: false) => void) | ((arg: true) => void)
```

You passed in what you thought was a single type and got a union of function types out.  Oops.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#37279](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37279))

---

And a union of function types can only be safely called with an *intersection* of their parameters.  Read the [TS3.3 release notes on support for calling a union of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for information about why this is.

But that means a value of type `OptionalArgBroken<boolean>` can only be called with an argument of type `true & false`, which is reduced to `never` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838)) because there is no value which is both `true` and `false`.

And *therefore*, when you try to call `haveArgBroken`, it expects the parameter passed in to be of type `never`:

```
const haveArgBroken: OptionalArgBroken<boolean> = function (b: boolean) { };
// haveArgBroken(arg: never): void
```

And `true` is not of type `never`, so it fails:

```
haveArgBroken(true); // Type error
```

**And that's why your original code did not work.**

---

Note that the same thing happens with

```
type ExtendsUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

but it is benign because `ExtendsUndefined<boolean>` becomes `ExtendsUndefined<true> | ExtendsUndefined<false>` which is `'no' | 'no'` which is reduced to just `'no'`.  It happens to be what you want, but only because there's no way to distinguish the `'no'` that came from `true` with the one that came from `false`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwIICcDmAQjkgNYQoA8ueAfFALxTVQQAew5AJgM5QCuKThABmCFBE5QA-AFgAUFEVQAFAEoGdAG5IEkgFzylKtPj1N86+lp2cA3PPkBjVN2BRufMGBwRu3akSk5GZwiKiYAcRklAJCouKcdIzCAo5hKCrqAN5QAL72ch5ePn6RQShqtlAA9NVQAGJiEA5yoJBQBEhIGAxQwDh80AA+UMKY3BAFtX3g0J3dvQBGXRgQaCgtbdAwWATzPYyhyOjY+IHRFMvdayg0U3VbsLv7vcrKJnhmYxgTlta66hGbw+Zn6gz+UG0AJazhQrigAAs0JoIGVoiF4McImcouRLisbklRql0ipFmYrqt1tk8vdEcjUTjyu9TFBxCicKozFDOPIkSi0eRlGCIKoqtMACqzFg4Yg4TbSgCi7C43AAqoIRE1OBQJUSJSwVYJeLEtQlpFAAOQgXyWqBmS0oJCWmEuNwAWTQZG4AGVyBMJV17VBlRxjRq4tqKKb4hIidbbQVYfDPd6-XCIBKET5oGZQ6qI2aJPjrut407LVUgA)