# Determine function signature from presence of another property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

A React component I am adding typing for is expected to support two different `onChange` event handler signatures, determined via the presence of another property (`field`).
I've read up on [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927169/1527562) by @jcalz, but have been unable to define `Props` to that `onChange` resolves to `ChangeHandlerNative`, unless `field` is present in which case it should be `ChangeHandlerLegacy`.
`field` can be `string` or `string[]`, but it would be acceptable to switch signatures on any non-null value.

The current solution I have incorrectly resolves `onChange` to `ChangeHandlerLegacy | ChangeHandlerNative` when I omit `field` entirely in the JSX usage, but it works as expected when `field` set to undefined or any other  value.

Typescript appears to default generic type parameters to `unknown` [since v3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown), but adding `T extends {}` as the docs suggested doesn't seem to work either.

I've also tried using discriminated unions, but it fails in similar fashion. Code and issues for that approach can be seen in [this Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=104#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAMIAWyAdgOZYAErwAmAGyxQAcshjAAbmwC8mKjAB0XXgICiinjGE9xkxizZb+Q0RKgAZLHzxM4KgBQFgWMSIBccVBgoYH4AGjgsfRh-bDwNS10ogEpXAD44eQhgEQZmVjgAVR4Aax4IAHceADEAVx58YAgeVzg3dXbkKD5Uf14mAG0AXRSldMzs3PMOEhAmgAViMHQVAG86OAzkMRqsAH5-QOD+OgBfSfyFiCXXdbgAHzgVuB5kECwDoJC+cM9vEX3npFJOEmgl3hxuFYjCZpLIFGwTnAAGTTECzHiXJa3B5PX4+D5HPj3AKffhDcIvN4AnhAqAgnhg-xg6G2BxOXAuREo9gzeaLVAMAh1BpNOAASR4YBqMDcYH5-kxqBST0oMBqUGaPBqYjEcDOdFwTUCcHK0GKXzZzhaAB4JVLCF4fEoyABGMhwUGQgRKFayxbhIEGEbpFYnREAelSdHD4bgAANPdosHG4CFDVBKPgxC5KKgIGJFOgYBB42C9FgDCzJJaOcTYvhNF6sOXKzZJHHfAajfAAEbEYoVmRyRQ2u3Sj0Mps+tyBmDBx5wQ08PMSdRiCB8GfJPURqMxuA6AAeYDEwFwwBg2bgcog8myX3jeJEKc8h6wRc4bDy7y7y-gpqgc1+CHeFR0lccnx9OoRCwTwaRERFKSwZ0AGZ3UTKxp1necniXFcsDXDctwrOcdzgSMgA)

**Edit:** Using discriminated unions would actually be better as the actual component uses generics with defaults, which from what I've read is not possible to combine with type parameters. I might be wrong though.

#### Minimal example

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAMIAWyAdgOZYAogDcsPGAAleAEwA2WKABksfPEzgBeOAAoCwLLOkAuOKhhRg-ADRwso8Sex4YAOi68BIsTACUmgHxwwhDA0owsbAAKxGCoADwAKoFaAN50cHB6BtIA-CYJ6XAQPO78WCYA2gkAurYAHjBi0ugVZhb8tTkc3GVe4lI8cgrKqrjqjlSupZ72kjLyUHQAvgwEAK48+MDFcACSPGBrMIn+2mAxqCbRELEnfilwlDBrUDxwPGuysnArdLjFZjgAHdoABrSx8EZqTRwOL7Q6EfSGDRkACMZCKJR6Ag0KTOMRsdm8fg0gRSSyWcAA9P46FSqXAAAbFaZYRlwSz-KCUfCydSUVAQWSidAwCBM1l9OaDBZQsZwAA+mEmbmxQlmAyGUEZRj+APgACNiKCxAA5ZAwYCiGFwg5HTGs3HaIniElkuD-HiC+QuWQQPjO2Z+CnU2n0uCCOpgWTAXDAGB8uDnCDCUIQplZQzsvR1LCizhsZisXWewEgqDg-jmy3WrS2hGZJHSXEbaRYPQ8LDSSkstVOl2+AJwB6loVYX3+wPEn6UmkMcMAVVQ6dwlAtQnkIG8jzznxg6EsTN7HjZKFkQOQTHQAqFqf4cDFTKc+FVJ6lmoWjJsMZNieka0LcVGUzaR2QNLB00ZDZQR4CAgR4Rk9S9Q1jTEOUmAAJhhZ9XFXHBGkETdvG0eEjhsB4QJMAByDCqJsY8yhMbRkBsA0bFwN0PQBMcJwDFi4DYj1gx8JCyzBCFqytLAsK0HCXDw9dCKwLdxBIu0YHIh01SYgdONHH0-QDXSfh8IA)

```
import * as React from "react";

type ChangeEventHandlerLegacy = (field: string, event: React.ChangeEvent) => void
type Props<T> = {
  field?: T
  onChange: [T] extends [string] ? ChangeEventHandlerLegacy : React.ChangeEventHandler
}

function Input<T>(props: Props<T>) { return null }

const workingLegacy = <Input field="1" onChange={(prop, event) => {}} />
// `onChange` incorrectly resolves to `ChangeEventHandlerLegacy | React.ChangeEventHandler`:
const brokenNative = <Input onChange={(event) => { console.log(event) }} />
// Explicitly providing `field` fixes the type:
const workingNative = <Input field={undefined} onChange={(event) => { console.log(event) }} />

// Using createElement results in `onChange` always resolving to `React.ChangeEventHandler`, likely due to `field` being `unknown`
const brokenLegacy2 = React.createElement(Input, { field: '2', onChange: (a, b, c) => console.log(a, b, c) })
const workingNative2 = React.createElement(Input, { onChange: (event) => console.log(event) })
```

#### Original question and code

This question has been revised to make it a bit more concise. The original version had a more elaborate example, which can be viewed on [this Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XaKvVWklqSVPDhYj1BoERr8MjkinWObgeY1UsbxT0WEaqZE5dtVckNad9etcFTiig-QQRwYHzYAAViGBUCKxeoC5r5SYqnAAN79fnGOYdLoY-qNZoiQ9nfoQHi2m14u1+Xn7oXLtJWgZDLCHnV8fq4MQ0FQGQD3aX86AAXwYAg23wYAbzgC4eDAYoYBFGxqjABdUHaecIEXN9BAAFRuKIkJQmBLE3Z44AAKQAZSuZwqOsHd-xvTodwaJoWjgCC5Sw-DUH6CR4BvW0BOw5xxIfFB0F7SJ+0dOtiNI8jUJY2x+mAb5qhnL5uPPewATgYFjzBbZd3qeoZI5OVqjTaxtlMOwrOs+o3UuW57gAJhoi5EXgSBUFQYAACMJHeT1+SgYh-TgWzwiiitHxNWJ4jgSM2DeERPX9NhUywERktwNB4CDGZ+ncwTF2k28H2qM8WjyBzpmcGBkCgAR4DQFASU2ZxBjGPJHJgTYqr4-ooPqSgYGKKAeDgJQegondnHWmrUH4xKBFMbcdqwfijiCKC6Bgng4IQ9SYB89Dqjc3Bik6EgJjgdbnE2yDcOwwiSLI5CNJlaw7BxB6nqTEB2jCiA4xwHg+ggyz+lm+bFqUa61o27D+IAoCQKwPbHue0h9UBImIfBdo2xEDseiKo6TuOU4vLuaoAGYaIOzLFKjTq+GKDJ0AIN4UwFLBkWKlbUPQTq2B6XBoEofANC8CEIGKPgQ04CAxwxBKxwhNhkQO8lZGPMLULYEQoTAQCmETak4AV2KsGVmc6AVnhOM0OUlGt+QP21g3HqgVA3iyuAAFpo+j+R3KTDosDYYNZHeEJUFwbowHgVAk8FfgxCYbmHbYZ2lfgGc8gtivHdKsQxDCvA-SDXOxG+MN5cV12YH6dGAfgfcCbIal64gMgEvqjk9ta5kdi4z2w4kZwxAgPgZ6ciD+KG0pTDIB5x+O-ptP79BA2DFEmpEclUFYXAdKaYr-WgP1eq0W+dDaXuMcv3edE6ceDrT2QFXPIuBnKuSdhxWGy9V7VGAXAMKoDNib0-GMXePkD4fn6E9PWCtwA3llHg4KQZ4KLVQNrOEj9n5RQgK0L+-cfIjjFrvEeK8AGT3CNPUa4D55QKXivNe3CUHbyHvvJ24MSBwEPvUPuFFGE-zIH-GA7DbRAJAU7Hh25IFe2gQIuB6iwHCK-Og8e5NJGHyUEcf2QRjjZhnHAPCBEFJcijGuFsABVHgPoeAQH9DwM4sE5AIXMAAeQ4ZWHmA5FCKnqAAHy4oPMC5k+B5EvoeUckg8gHXvByPsUZ+I4nYCQEAN5HHCTiVxS+STQSYnib+JUqo8iD3SWmKAWTwlYHaGE5x9pTQZQKRwYppTsJM3OpdRaVwlDsEEM2VInjvG+P8YE0hcpukPjyX080GFNpdMFGhMpeRASX3BPEwEB1AQg0qTxNoR4alwDqckxsjSJ53g4IIRG7QGJMU0mdZZCFJnTNmegeZPi-EBIukExaoSOl5KiVgbZ2FvpCSmYIGwNEvnMSBvANyKMFpLRvnSQ+p0xmQrgAATUwoihxP01m5MicpeF2J54SMhggmGEg6SIzYjNLAc08VKCuJjD62MpGM0nEAA).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My instinct is to use a union instead of a conditional but it is not working out like I hoped it would: https://tsplay.dev/m02Pqw

Comment: @LindaPaiste Indeed, that's about as far as I got too - and it also introduces the issue of type incompatibility of `field` in Input2. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: I managed to narrow down the issue to the omission of the `field` prop in the JSX now, and simplified the question a bit.