# Does extended types and intersection types of interfaces are equal?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand the behavior of the extended type and intersection type of interfaces in typescript. I already have a custom `Equal` utility to check extensionality.

```
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

interface One {
    zero: 'zero';
    one: 'one';
}

interface Two {
    two: 'two';
}

interface Three {
    three: 'three'
}

interface ExtendedType extends One, Two, Three {}

type IntersectionType = One & Two & Three;

// error missing properties are two, three
const example1: ExtendedType = { one: 'one', zero: 'zero'} 

// error missing properties are two three 
const example2: IntersectionType = {
    one: 'one',
    zero: 'zero'
}

type CheckEqual = Equal<ExtendedType, IntersectionType> // false why?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8ANANFAmgPigF4AoKKACjQBV8KBKYw6qCAD2AgDsATAZygYoAfigBGKAC4oAJkbtOvPmUo06jIs1Ydu-PCPFTZjUcABOCaNIBmqPhBIkAll05nbAY2gB5LtADeKuQAXhBmAPbSAOShEVEA3EFQ4X7RKRAJJAC+ji5untDUAO7hUIHk5MAl0VXhmTnOrmEFUNQAFmYQAUnAHV01fRnZuU3uSF6wOrwQPNTg0Aq6Ar4QOMXha4NlDaCQUACSo-YewE4pc3tEUCtQAGStJXetg4kku9AAwm0QHgDW8MgUMRYIhUGgYFMeDMLqsDkcfqdzvNCAB6FFQWwoeyODwpPjAbRIAC2YBQEDE0ghiihs3mwP8yVSUCi6SiOFikWZHKiDVxXHxhJJZJk0kObmOiK4MPpSXSaT8bKgSQ50W5wxIQA)

Both the type have somewhat similar messages and checks for missing properties. I thought both will be equal as they are doing the same job. However, when I check the extensionality of the two types `ExtendedType` and `IntersectionType`, it results in false.

I think I am missing some important behavior of extended and intersection types.

I really get confused about which one of the types should I use. Is it either `ExtendedType` or `IntersectionType`? Are both types are doing the same thing?

Comment: How is your `Equal` supposed to work? I can see no logic to it.

Comment: See [this](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) for the logic of `Equal`. The two types `ExtendedType` and `IntersectionType` are *mutually assignable*; you can pretty much always use one in place of the other. But the compiler represents them differently, and the `Equal` check here cares about such *identical internal representation*.  In some sense: four quarters are "equal to" one dollar, but they are represented differently and so might not be considered "identical to" each other. For most purposes you probably care about "equal" and not "identical"

Comment: This question isn't *quite* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807517/how-to-test-if-two-types-are-exactly-the-same, but it's dependent on it, given that it hinges on what it means for two types to be "equal"

Comment: @jcalz very self-explanatory comment!! It would be easier for everyone (like sharing) if you write the same thing in the answer. Especially about identical representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Equal` seems... off.

If you define it like this it is `true` as expected:

```
type Equal<X, Y> = [X] extends [Y] ? [Y] extends [X] ? true : false : false;
```

The types are equal as far as the type system goes. The main difference here is that `interface` creates types, while `type` aliases add a different name to refer to an existing type.

The [old documentation notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases):

> Almost all features of an `interface` are available in `type`, the key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable.

```
interface Window {
  title: string
}

interface Window {
  ts: import("typescript")
}

const src = 'const a = "Hello World"';
window.ts.transpileModule(src, {});
```

```
type Window = {
  title: string
}

type Window = {
  ts: import("typescript")
}

// Error: Duplicate identifier 'Window'.
```

> Because an interface more closely maps how JavaScript objects work by being open to extension, we recommend using an interface over a type alias when possible.
> On the other hand, if you can’t express some shape with an interface and you need to use a union or tuple type, type aliases are usually the way to go.

(Strangely the new documentation is very unhelpful in that it currently does not explain any of this.)

Comment: Do you mean they are equal? If yes would you elaborate more in your answer?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Added a note on the difference.

Comment: Would you also add examples of the differences between the two?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Corrected an error in my statement and added more info.

Comment: one last question: in my example `IntersectionType` would be better as I am not adding any new properties? or still ExtendedType?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik: I would probably recommend using the `interface` type, because it is more future-proof and using `type` is not required. I mainly use `type` for types based on literals and other union based types (e.g. `type Direction = 'left' | 'right'`) which you cannot do with an interface.

Comment: You should probably change your test not to be distributive (i.e., `[X] extends [Y] ? [Y] extends [X] ? true : false : false`) or weird things will happen with unions (e.g., `Equal<boolean, boolean>` will be `boolean`, not `true` in your version). The `Equal` from the question isn't "off" so much as it is doing a different sort of equality check from what you're doing; you are checking for *mutual assignability* while the original one is more like *identical representation*. See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) and the whole issue.

Comment: @jcalz: Can you explain what is going on in the `boolean` case or point me to an existing explanation? That seems highly illogical.

Comment: Your original version uses [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so `Equal<A | B, C | D>` will end up being evaluated as `Equal<A, C> | Equal<B, C> | Equal<A, D> | Equal<B, D>` which I imagine is not the point.

Comment: @jcalz: Oh, so `boolean` is expanded to `true | false` and that is what gets distributed?

Comment: Yes, `boolean`'s internal representation is a union, `true | false`.  The quickinfo of IntelliSense will *display* a union containing `true | false` as one containing `boolean` instead, but the internal representation is the union; it's not a single type.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926729/why-does-a-typescript-type-conditional-on-t-extends-undefined-with-t-instanti) for an example of how `boolean` trips people up with distributive conditional types