# Typescript Conditional Types not working as expected

Tags: typescript

`type Equals<T, R> = T extends R ? (R extends T ? true : false) : false;` ([playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-elbakyan-evrl1s?file=/src/index.ts))

Why does this utility type always returns boolean, shouldn't it return true or false?

*Edit:*
After a bit digging, I found that *mutual assignability* is not the same thing as *type equality* in typescript due to the existence of type `any`([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212/14218672)). So my type here should probably be better described as
`type MutualAssignable<T, R> = T extends R ? (R extends T ? true : false) : false;`

However, it doesn't answer the question of why the result is always boolean. (I tested with `boolean` and `false` in TS 4.4.4, 4.6.4 and 4.8.4, they all return the same result). Actually, after some testing, I think the *true branch* will always present in the result, which I don't think is correct IMHO.

Comment: Please add code or a playground link where you get the issue you describe when using your generic type. A simple test with your type in a playground gave false/true and not boolean

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information, I added a simple playground here: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-elbakyan-evrl1s?file=/src/index.ts, type Test is boolean instead of true / false

Comment: The term you should search for here is "[distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)" which explains the behavior (along with the fact that `boolean` in TS is a synonym for the union `true | false`). See the [linked q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926729/why-does-a-typescript-type-conditional-on-t-extends-undefined-with-t-instanti) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After some serious digging of the issue list of typescript, it turns out that typescript conditional types will **discriminate the union type** passed to it unless wrapped in array or tuple.

So for the `MutableAssignment` type, when testing with `type T = MutableAssignable<true|false, false>`, it will be transformed to `type T = MutableAssignable<true, false> | MutableAssignable<false, false>`, thus fails for any *partial type comparisons*.

So the right way to define this utility type is `type MutableAssignable<T, R> = [T] extends [R] ? ([R] extends [T] ? true : false) : false`

Comment: A simpler way of defining this type is `type MutuallyAssignable<A, B> = [A, B] extends [B, A] ? true : false`.